# Pandas dataframe trying to retrieve integer in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which is as follows:

```
    s = index_df[(index_df['id2'].values  == result[z][3])]
    print s.iloc[:, [0]]
```

which will give me the result

```
      id1
36  14559
```

I'm trying to store the value 14559 into a variable with the following:

```
value = s.iloc[:, [0]]
```

But it keeps giving me an error:

```
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame
```

Any idea how i could solve this?

**EDIT**:

My dataframe are declared as follows:

result:

```
result=[(fuzz.WRatio(n, n2),n2,sdf.index[x],bdf.index[y])
        for y, n2 in enumerate(Col2['CSGNE_NAME']) if fuzz.WRatio(n, n2)>80 and len(n2) >= 2
       ]
```

And this is how i declare and append to the dataframe:

```
index_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id1','id2', 'score'])
index_df = index_df.append({'id1':result[z][2], 'id2':result[z][3], 'score':result[z][0]}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe need:

```
s.iloc[:, 0]
```

Or:

```
s.iloc[0, 0]
```

Or convert values to list and use `next` for extract first value:

```
L = index_df[(index_df['id2'].values  == result[z][3])].values.tolist()

#use parameter if not matched condition and returned empty val
out = next(iter(L), 'no matched value')
```

**Sample**:

```
index_df = pd.DataFrame({'id2':[1,2,3,2],
                         'id1':[10,20,30,40]})
print (index_df)
   id2  id1
0    1   10
1    2   20
2    3   30
3    2   40

#if possible specify column name with .loc (`id1`)
L = index_df.loc[index_df['id2'].values == 2, 'id1']
#use parameter if not matched condition and returned empty val
#out = next(iter(L), 'no matched value')
print (out)
20
```

Comment: If i use your code, i encounter StopIteration right away without any sort of output

Comment: Yes, problem is with empty value, use second one. I edit answer for it now.

Comment: What is `result` ? Another df? Or some dict?

Comment: just edited the original post, it's a fuzzywuzzy comparsion between 2 excel files

Comment: @dythe - So `result` is called in loop ? Is possible some values are emty and not possible indexing like `[z][2]` ? Not easy for me find problem because cannot run your solution, because no data. Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: result will never be empty as there always a minimum of 1 result and it is in a for loop

Comment: @dythe - OK, so still same error? If error, what return `L` ?

Comment: Series([], Name: id1, dtype: object) - it's empty if i use your method

Comment: So it means `index_df[(index_df['id2'].values  == result[z][3])]` return nothing? so `result[z][3]` is nothing ?

Comment: result[z][2] and result[z][3] will always have a value

Comment: @dythe - hmmm, then what is reason why filtering `index_df[(index_df['id2'].values == result[z][3])]` return no rows? Because if always some values it should working.